# Fetching message type PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces and submitting a form. An error message is thrown in case any exception occurs in the backing bean. I need to perform some operation using javascript incase of error message.
Currently I am using the following code but I am getting facesContext.maximumSeverity as null.

```
    <p:commandButton action="#{backingBean.fetchSearchResults()}"
update="@form :searchResults" value="Update" 
actionListener="#{backingBean.updateDetails()}" validateClient="true"
oncomplete="handleResponse(xhr, status, args)" />

<h:outputScript target="head">
    function handleResponse(xhr, status, args) {
        if( args.notValid || args.validationFailed) {
            alert('Balls 1');
            return;
        } else if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null or facesContext.maximumSeverity.compareTo(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR) ge 0}) {
            alert('Balls 2');
            return;
        } else if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null or facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal=='1'}) {
            alert('Balls 3');
            return;
        } else {
            alert('Everything is Ok.');
        }
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: I don't think you can access static variables from EL, and I'm not sure you can use compareTo either. Is the "==null" just for testing?

Comment: No I did some research and found out the above solution.

Comment: What I need to do is close the popup on successful db insertion and it should remain open in case of any validation message or exception. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong assumption that `#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null or facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal=='1'}` is evaluated when the javascript is called. It is NOT. It is evaluated when the page is rendered. At that moment, the value is most likely null for the severity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to close the popup on a successful db insertion and it should remain open in case of any validation message or exception. Can you please help me out?